# three axis in $\mathbb{A}^3$ can't be defined by two functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I am reading Shafarevich's book on Algebraic Geometry and in 1.6.5, exercise 3. He asks to prove that $X \subset \mathbb{A}^3$, which is the union of the three coordinate axis, can not be defined by two functions. i.e. $I(X)$ must be generated by at least three elements.

I am lost on how to solve this problem.

Comment: $I(X)=( x y, x z, y z )$

Comment: See the hint for an analogous problem with another monomial ideal http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976156/showing-that-an-ideal-is-not-generated-by-two-elements/

Comment: Two solutions: here http://math.stackexchange.com/a/92518/3217 and here http://math.stackexchange.com/a/510997/3217

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Thanks! Those two answers were really helpful!

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/determining-the-generators-of-ix